# How to TRANSPOSE MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql

My **customer** table is given below,

[image: customer]

I need to transpose this table to **customer_new**

[image]

What is the easiest way.. I tried `SELECT` data and `INSERT` method, but is was difficult and more coding.

Any idea?

i tried , but **not worked!**

Comment: What you are trying to do is known as a PIVOT which is not natively supported in MYSQL. See this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581482/transpose-mysql-query-need-rows-into-columns

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transpose MySQL query - need rows into columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581482/transpose-mysql-query-need-rows-into-columns)

Comment: i tried but, not working

Comment: Then try again, because it is supposed to work :) What does not work? Please update your question with the query you have tried and a desription of the failure, if needed.