# Convert multiple Rows into Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, rows, multiple-columns

I have a table from my script SQL e.g.:

[image]

I need to convert this table into:

[image]

I create temporary table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table
(
  Data Date,
  Max Real,
  Min Real,
  Avg Real
)
```

I have a script, when my values are calculated and next:

```
INSERT INTO #Table (Data, Max, Min, Avg) VALUES (@Data, @Max, @Min, @Avg)
```

I don't know, how to convert `table1` into `table2`

Comment: Maybe the links in the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20804382/sql-server-querying-multiple-rows-returning-in-one) could help you find your way.

Comment: you need to use `pivot`

Comment: @WingedPanther I know already, I need to use pivot, but I don't know how need to use pivot, I may succeed

Answer (score 0):

This is called "transposing" the data.

In some databases, the PIVOT command can be used for this purpose. When it doesn't exist, for example in MySQL, it can be done using GROUP BY and sometimes tangled SQL, as in the following examples:

- [Transpose MySQL query - need rows into columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581482/transpose-mysql-query-need-rows-into-columns)
- [How to transpose mysql table rows into columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568228/how-to-transpose-mysql-table-rows-into-columns)
- [MySql Transpose Row into Column and Column into Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019453/mysql-transpose-row-into-column-and-column-into-row)

It is however normally much simpler do the transposing in your import script.

A key requirement for either option is that your transposed table needs a fixed number of columns; in the example you provide, this isn't the case.

An alternative, which could be more appropriate here, is to leave the data as-is in the database, and transpose it later on in the application that uses/views the data.

Comment: Thank You, I'll try to do it,  I may succeed

Comment: My data is selected from the loop and I can't enter it's "rigidly" how month in 2th link

Comment: @Mini ,  do you have a fixed number of columns, i.e. a certain number of data points, or not? Because if not, you cannot use these methods. A database table needs a predetermined number of columns.

Comment: I don't use a fixed number of columns ehhh :/

Comment: Then, as I mention in the answer, I suggest you store the data in the database in this format; and do the transposing when you are viewing/showing/reporting the data.

Answer (score 0):

I would love to see more answers for this question here is my version

```
SELECT 'Data' AS [Data],* FROM (
SELECT DATA FROM #TABLE)A
PIVOT
(
MAX(DATA ) FOR DATA IN ([08:01],[08:02],[08:03],[08:04])
)B
UNION ALL
SELECT 'MAX',CONVERT(VARCHAR,[26]),CONVERT(VARCHAR,[27]),CONVERT(VARCHAR,        [28]),CONVERT(VARCHAR,[29]) FROM (
SELECT [MAX] FROM #TABLE)A
PIVOT
(
    MAX([MAX]) FOR [MAX] IN ([26],[27],[28],[29])
)B
UNION ALL
SELECT 'MIN',CONVERT(VARCHAR,[20]),CONVERT(VARCHAR,[21]),CONVERT(VARCHAR,    [22]),CONVERT(VARCHAR,[23]) FROM (
SELECT [MIN] FROM #TABLE)A
PIVOT
(
    MAX([MIN]) FOR [MIN] IN ([20],[21],[22],[23])
)B
UNION ALL
SELECT 'AVG',CONVERT(VARCHAR,[23]),CONVERT(VARCHAR,[24]),CONVERT(VARCHAR,    [25]),CONVERT(VARCHAR,[26]) FROM (
SELECT [AVG] FROM #TABLE)A
PIVOT
(
    MAX([AVG]) FOR [AVG] IN ([23],[24],[25],[26])
)B
```

tried to attach an image, but unable to do!

Comment: Thank You. I'll try to do it,but my table is dynamic (table isn't 4x4). whichever I will choose the time interval, so will the rows. One note: with my table 08.01, 08.02 etc. aren't time, only 1th August, 2th August etc.